# ReactJS Change build folder location in Windows

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-scripts

In `package.json` I am passing the absolute location of the build folder as follows

```
"scripts":{
  "build": "set BUILD_PATH=C:/Tomcat/webapps && react-scripts build",
  ...
}
```

When I run the `npm run build` command, 2 empty folders are created, and inside that files and folders are getting stored

Example of build folder: `C/Tomcat/webapps/../../all_build_files`

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost it is supposed to be:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build": "[...]",
[...]
}
```

eg. `scripts` instead of `script`

---

You could also use `build-win` instead of just `build` but I am guessing that it doesn't matter for now.

However, on to your issue, it should work (at least it does for me) when adding this into the `.env`. Alternatively you can just copy the output of the build folder into some other folder with `cp` or `copy` since you are using windows.

```
// .env file
BUILD_PATH=foo
```

---

In the documentation it is also noted that it should be **relative** to the root of your project and not absolute. Maybe that is where it fails and creates your two weird directories.

| Variable | Development | Production | Usage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BUILD_PATH | Ignored | ✅ Used | By default, Create React App will output compiled assets to a `/build` directory adjacent to your `/src`. You may use this variable to specify a new path for Create React App to output assets. `BUILD_PATH` should be specified as a path relative to the root of your project. |

> Source: [Create React App Documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/)

Comment: Can we pass the absolute path in the .env file?

Comment: @HarshKanakhara yes it should absolutely work. Pun intended